# How to instruct apache Tomee 8 to use Jackson as provider for JAX-RS instead of default Johnzon for my application?

Tags: jackson, jax-rs, tomee-8

I've a simple test JEE application to test how can I force it to use Jackson instead of Johnzon as Jax-RS provider.

Here are the classes that I've added to the project so far:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class HelloApplication extends Application {

}
```

and

```
@Path("/hello-world")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable =  { SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT })
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

and here is pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.7.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-providers</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I've tried the updating the system.properties file with

> openejb.jaxrs.jsonProviders=com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
> and adding a openejb-jar.xml file with content of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<openejb-jar xmlns="http://www.openejb.org/openejb-jar/1.1">
    <pojo-deployment  class-name="jaxrs-application">
        <properties>
            cxf.jaxrs.providers = com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
        </properties>
    </pojo-deployment>
</openejb-jar>
```

So far I've tried every solution on stack overflow that had been provided for prior versions but nothing seem to work. Can anyone help me with this problem?

I've tested the application against Tomee 8.0.13 and 8.0.14 and got the same results.

Comment: Try override `getProperties()` in Application classs

Comment: @PaulSamsotha what should I overwrite it to?

Comment: Override that method in your Application class. Add the property to the Map